# Android kotlin logging library

Tags: android, kotlin, logging

I need a logging library for android, that will:

- write logs to a file somewhere at `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myproject/files/logs/`
- the log file should be named somehow `2021-01-01.17-39-29.txt`
- I'd like to have the ability to specify how many files the `logs` directory can have.
  I.e. for example if I set max files to 20. It will auto delete older log files.
- I want to control the logging process, so that the library will write to a file only when I call the method, e.g. : `logfile.log(data)`

Now, I know there are a lot of questions about android logging on stackoverflow, but I'd like to find the library that would fit all my needs. In case if you know a good one, I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) to manage logging (this library supports logging for debugging and production purposes).

Then, you need to write a function to write logs into disk.

For example:

```kotlin
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // Default debug tree 
    // A Tree for debug builds. Automatically infers the tag from the calling class. 
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
} else {
    // Implement your custom Tree if need, eg. enable crashlytics,...
}
```

You now can write function to write logs into disk by override `DebugTree` class:

```kotlin
Timber.plant(object: Timber.DebugTree() {

        // for example, if you need to write log when catched exceptions
        override fun e(t: Throwable?) {
            super.e(t)
        }

        // or here to check for all tags
        override fun createStackElementTag(element: StackTraceElement): String? {
            return super.createStackElementTag(element)
        }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.